# Installing newrelic with Dokku

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5, dokku

I have dokku installed with a laravel application deployed on it with Apache configuration. I Googled how to install newrelic on dokku but did not find any reliable source.

Please share your experience installing newrelic with PHP agent on dokku

Answer (score 0):

have you tried  with this plugin for dokku?

https://github.com/aegypius/dokku-newrelic